# With a $Gamma(2, \frac{1}{2} )$ use the CLT to prove the random variables $ \sqrt{n}( \overline{X}_{n} - 1) \rightarrow_{d} N(0, \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem, gamma-distribution

I'm currently noodling through a proof as to why a Gamma distribution of $Gamma(2, \frac{1}{2} )$ converges as per the Central Limit theorem:
$$ \sqrt{n}( \overline{X}_{n} - \mu)  \rightarrow_{d}  N(0, \sigma^{2}$$

Also, from the Gamma Distribution I know that:
$$E(X) = \alpha\beta = 1$$
$$Var(X) = \alpha\beta^{2} = 1/2$$ When I plug these value in I get: $ \sqrt{n}( \overline{X}_{n} - 1)  \rightarrow_{d}  N(0, \frac{1}{2})$.

My understanding starts to fall apart when I use the formula :

$$Z_{n} = \frac{\overline{X}_{n}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$$ I get:
$Z_{n}=\sqrt{2n}(\overline{X}_{n}-1)$ Which kind of looks like $ \sqrt{n}( \overline{X}_{n} - 1)$ with the $n$ being scaled by a factor of $2$. I'm fully aware that $\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \sqrt{2n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \sqrt{n}$. So maybe this is the fact I'm supposed to use.

But I'd like to have a clear understanding of how to precisely prove the convergence rather than plugging in values and saying it's done.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n - 1) \to N(0, 1/2)$ and $Z_n \to N(0, 1)$ and $X_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} Z_n$ do not contradict each other.

Comment: You are not supposed to use $\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \sqrt{2n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \sqrt{n}$ - both are infinite but before taking the limit the left hand side is $\sqrt{2}$ times the right hand side.  To prove convergence, you might want to use characteristic functions or something similar